# Is the implementation of `dpkg-query -S` really necessary in C?

Tags: dpkg

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1314173/where-are-the-database-files-queried-by-dpkg-query/1314175

As discussed here, all the `dpkg-query -S` files are in `/var/lib/dpkg/info/*.list`.

The following test shows that a simple `grep` command is much faster than `dpkg-query -S`. Is it really necessary to implement in `dpkg-query -S` in C given that it is not faster and it is not obvious to see what files `dpkg-query -S` actually queries?

```
$ time dpkg-query -S /bin/ls
coreutils: /bin/ls

real    0m0.176s
user    0m0.116s
sys 0m0.060s
$ time grep -H '^/bin/ls$' /var/lib/dpkg/info/*.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/coreutils.list:/bin/ls

real    0m0.091s
user    0m0.075s
sys 0m0.016s
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though the layout and format of the dpkg database is administrator friendly, and it is expected that those might need to mess with it perhaps in recovery situations or in case of emergency, this “interface” does not extend to other programs besides the dpkg suite of tools.

See this lintian check triggering on such accesses:
https://lintian.debian.org/tags/uses-dpkg-database-directly

And see the following spec, for an upcoming change that will break any such direct uses, instead of using the officially supported interfaces:
https://wiki.debian.org/Teams/Dpkg/Spec/MetadataTracking